# ELASTICSEARCH Watcher

Tags: elasticsearch, elasticsearch-watcher

need the watcher to differentiate between 2 values of the same field:
Within the latency_info field in the task "Integration" I need to differentiate whether in the task Integration the result field is "-" or "200".

"latency_info": [
{
"task": "Start",
"started": 0
},
{
"result": "-",
"task": "Authorize",
"started": "-",
"id": "-"
},
{
"result": "500",
"task": "Authorizer",
"started": "29000",
"id": "-"
},
{
"result": "-",
"task": "Authenticate",
"started": "-",
"id": "-"
},
{
"result": "-",
"task": "Integration",
"started": "-",
"id": "-"
}

But I am unable to do it.

Any suggestions?

I have tried with must or must_not but no result

Comment: Can anyone help me?